# How to configure Elixir, NGINX, Websockets on server

Tags: ssl, nginx, websocket, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm setting up a server with a Phoenix app that will use websockets. Locally websocket work but I have problems with setting it up on my staging server. Can someone help me with setting up websockets on my server. I have nginx configured like this:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream my_app {
  server 0.0.0.0:6443;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/wildcard.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/wildcard.key;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  if ($request_uri ~ "^[^?]*//") {
    rewrite "(.*)" $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
  }
  if ( $scheme = http ){
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
  }

  location / {
    allow all;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Cluster-Client-Ip $remote_addr;

    # WebSockets
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass https://my_app;
  }
}
```

and my phoenix config is:

```
use Mix.Config

config :my_app_core, MyAppCoreWeb.Endpoint,
  load_from_system_env: false,
  url: [host: "https://example.com", port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  https: [otp_app: :my_app_core, port: 6443, keyfile: "/path/to/wildcard.key", certfile: "/path/to/wildcard.crt"],
  server: true,
  root: ".",
  watchers: [],
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version],
  check_origin: false

config :logger, :console, format: "[$level] $message\n"

config :phoenix, :stacktrace_depth, 2

config :phoenix, :serve_endpoints, true

import_config "workspace.secret.exs"
```

I'm testing the connection with http://phxsockets.io/ and I get

```
failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: I would expect that `proxy_pass https://my_app;` has to refer to somewhere localhost and as you are handling ssl on nginx level, I do not see a point that you proxy your app over https. Try regular `http` instead.

Comment: I tried changing from `proxy_pass https://my_app;` to `proxy_pass http://my_app;` and it didn't change anything. In the phoenix config file I set up the `http` and `https` and it should be enough to work with websockets (`ws` and `wss`). As for localhost, I tested it by changing the `upstream my_app { server 0.0.0.0:6443;}` to `upstream my_app { server 0.0.0.0:4020;}` (my port for http) or by using both `upstream my_app { server 0.0.0.0:6443; server 0.0.0.0:4020}`. This also resulted in the same issue.

Comment: I think you also need to specify the websocket port on proxy_pass. Else it will be listening on port 80 or port 443 depending. Could you try `proxy_pass http://my_app:4020`

Comment: still the same issue :( I've added the port like you said and I have tried `proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:4020` and this also didn't work. I think it doesn't matter if you set it in `proxy_pass` or you define `upstream my_app { server 0.0.0.0:4020 }`

Comment: ok, this config is working. The problem was with updating the wrong nginx config for this app :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above configuration works. The issue on my side was with using the wrong nginx config file that had the old settings.