# Elixir websockets on server with https

Tags: nginx, elixir, phoenix-framework

I create one application in Elixir and this application use channels/websockets . Locally websocket works but in staging dont . 
Can someone help me with setting up websockets on my server?

In staging when try connect i have error:

```
Unexpected response code: 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closes this topic with question

[How to configure Elixir, NGINX, Websockets on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47839601/how-to-configure-elixir-nginx-websockets-on-server)

https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/

Probably you need config in nginx .